# Prevent the Form from being resized from its bottom border

Tags: c#, winforms

I like to be avble to resize the form by dragging its right side border...so I set BorderStyle to sizable, but at the same time I don't want to be able to resize it by dragigng its Bottom border, So I want to be able to resize the form horizontally but not vertically.

I thought well if I set the same value of the Height for both MinSize and MaxSize proprieties it should work but nop! as soon as I enter a non-zero value for Height it starts to think that Zero for Width is also important...which is wrong.

If I need to "code" for it, then never mind. Not worth of it. But if there some properties I can set I my form to do this, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set MaximumSize to be {99999, yourHeight} and MinimumSize to be {0,yourHeight}. The designer does indeed think that the zero dimension of a nonzero size is important; so don't specify a width of zero as the maximum.